# Why was the 'thread' module renamed to '_thread' in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

Python 3.x renamed the low-level module 'thread' to '_thread' -- I don't see why in the documentation. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the thread module became obsolete in 3.x in favor of the threading module. See [PEP 3108](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/#obsolete).

Answer (score 10):

It's been quite a long time since the low-level `thread` module was informally deprecated, with all users heartily encouraged to use the higher-level `threading` module instead; now with the ability to introduce backwards incompatibilities in Python 3, we've made that deprecation rather more than just "informal", that's all!-)

Comment: I really like the one-liner thread.start_new_thread(*) approach though.  I think it's the most pythonic way to create a thread.  I hate having to type 3 lines of code to do the same thing.

Comment: What's Pythonic is to have "one, and preferably only one, obvious way" to perform a task. If one-liners are your goal, Perl may be more suitable for you than Python, which never particularly targeted them.

Comment: Why does the one and preferably only one obvious way to perform a task have to be unnecessarily verbose? If unnecesarily verbose code is your goal, Java may be more suitable for you than Python :-P

Answer (score 7):

I think the old `thread` module is deprecated in favour of the higher level [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) module.